# Django and Python Wamp-like web development environment

Tags: windows, python, mysql, django

For PHP developer, they often use web development environment tool such as [Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) to develop their web application as such tools provide Apache, PHP and MySQL in a single package.

I would like to know if there are Wamp-like tool for Django and Python. For the time being, I call this tool WAMPPD, and it will offer Apache, PHP, MySQL, Python and Django in a single package.

Comment: Did you even Google? A search for `Django Python Wamp` brings up a whole bunch of tutorials on how to set this up.

Comment: @Mawg, should look something like Portable Python except that it has a GUI Control Panel that look something like WAMPP.